# Reduce not geting the right values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to make an array of arrays, where shoud be like:

```
{ 
    data: [0, 0, 0], 
    name: '' 
}
```

I made a simple code to test may real one and I noted that it is getting `-1` on data where it should be other numbers.

So with the code above I should be able to do this:

```
0:
data: (12) [18093941, 18093941, 18093941, 18093941, 18093941, 18093941, 18093941, 18093941, 18093941, 18093941, 18093941, 35554793]
name: "Fuel"
```

What I am doing wrong?

```js
const input = [
    {
      Data: '01/01/2009 00:00:00',
      Fuel: '43575070.000',
      Diesel: '5963754.000',
      monthSingle: '01'
    },
    {
      Data: '01/02/2009 00:00:00',     
      Fuel: 'NULL',
      Diesel: '1509490.000',
      monthSingle: '02'
    },
    {
      Data: '01/03/2009 00:00:00',
      Fuel: '21061010.000',
      Diesel: '6887.000',
      monthSingle: '03'
    },

    {
      Data: '01/04/2009 00:00:00',
      Fuel: '21061010.000',
      Diesel: '6887.000',
      monthSingle: '04'
    }
  ]
  const MesesOptions = [
    {
      id: 1,
      value: '01',
      label: 'Janeiro',
      sufix: 'Jan'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      value: '02',
      label: 'Fevereiro',
      sufix: 'Fev'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      value: '03',
      label: 'Março',
      sufix: 'Mar'
    }
  ]
  const TheOutPut = input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    // console.log(acc, cur)
return [
      {
        name: 'Fuel',
        data: MesesOptions.map((month) =>
          parseFloat(acc.find((x) => x.name === 'Fuel').data.indexOf(month.id -1)) +
          parseFloat(cur.monthSingle === month.value ? cur.Fuel ?? 0 : 0))
      }
    ]
  }, [
    { name: 'Fuel', data: [] }, { name: 'Aux', data: [0] }
  ]
  )
  console.log(TheOutPut)
```

Comment: It would be loads more helpful if you could post some sample inputs and their desired outputs as well.

Comment: What's `cur.mes` in the second `ParseFloat`?

Comment: @RoboMop i just posted the inputs on the code snippet... and on the start os question i show what is the desired outputs

Comment: What I think it's happening is: the first `parseFloat` returns -1 because it's what `indexOf` returns if you don't find the value, which is what happens since `data` is empty, and the second `ParseFloat` returns 0 since that boolean evaluates to False, so suming that you get your -1.

Comment: @bernatj the first month is the current month validation

Comment: @bernatj 
ok i got it now... i'm trying to store the fuel values ​​inside the data array during a map of the months, but i'm not able to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not sure of what you wanted so I have provided two probable solutions based on an assumption of what I think you might be looking for.

```js
const input = [{
    Data: '01/01/2009 00:00:00',
    Ilha: '1',
    Fuel: '43575070.000',
    Diesel: '5963754.000',
    TermFuel: 'NULL',
    Hidrica: '2084379.000',
    Geotermica: '14775549.410',
    Eolica: '3771650.000',
    Biogas: '2502.000',
    Aux: '1634838.600'
  },
  {
    Data: '01/02/2009 00:00:00',
    Ilha: '1',
    Fuel: 'NULL',
    Diesel: '1509490.000',
    TermFuel: 'NULL',
    Hidrica: 'NULL',
    Geotermica: 'NULL',
    Eolica: '296600.000',
    Biogas: 'NULL',
    Aux: '56909.000'
  },
  {
    Data: '01/03/2009 00:00:00',
    Ilha: '1',
    Fuel: '21061010.000',
    Diesel: '6887.000',
    TermFuel: 'NULL',
    Hidrica: '1534690.000',
    Geotermica: '14775549.410',
    Eolica: 'NULL',
    Biogas: '2502.000',
    Aux: '478623.000'
  },

  {
    Data: '02/01/2009 00:00:00',
    Ilha: '1',
    Fuel: '21061010.000',
    Diesel: '6887.000',
    TermFuel: 'NULL',
    Hidrica: '1534690.000',
    Geotermica: '14775549.410',
    Eolica: 'NULL',
    Biogas: '2502.000',
    Aux: '478623.000'
  }
];

const MesesOptions = [{
    id: 1,
    value: '01',
    label: 'Janeiro',
    suffix: 'Jan'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: '02',
    label: 'Fevereiro',
    suffix: 'Fev'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    value: '03',
    label: 'Março',
    suffix: 'Mar'
  }
];

const results = input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const keyVals = Object.entries(cur);
  keyVals.map(([k, v], i) => {
    const nameData = acc.find(a => a.name == k);
    if (nameData) {
      nameData.data = MesesOptions.map((m) => 0);
    }
  });

  return acc;
}, [{
  name: 'Fuel',
  data: []
}, {
  name: 'Aux',
  data: [0]
}]);

const results2 = input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const keyVals = Object.entries(cur);
  keyVals.map(([k, v], i) => {
    const nameData = acc.find(a => a.name == k);
    if (nameData && !Number.isNaN(Number(v))) {
      nameData.data.push(parseFloat(v));
    }
  });

  return acc;
}, [{
  name: 'Fuel',
  data: []
}, {
  name: 'Aux',
  data: [0]
}]);

console.log(results);
console.log(results2);
```

Comment: tahnsks for the help, tat is what i was looking for, just a question, the results inside data shoud be number, so should i use parseFloat ? and where to put that?

Comment: Yes you can use `parseFloat` and filter out not a number values

Comment: @NoobDEV-GBL I have updated the code to use `parseFloat`.